# MVC ERP Solutions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, webforms, erp

I am looking at the viability of designing a full scale ASP.NET MVC Application. I want to know the following points :

=> **Is it possible** ? Is the architecture of MVC Designed for large - scale heavy traffic web applications which deal the with a lot of data handling ?( Concerns like bringing lot of data to the Client ? will it slow it down ? )  What are the features which make it easy to use or difficult to use for designing heavy applications.

In this regard, i would like to know more about the Entity Framework which is responsible for all the data transactions .

=> **Examples** of Web applications designed in MVC which deal with a lot of traffic.

=> **Links** on resources which can include sample projects , tutorials , lectures, Example Codes etc .

=> **Expert Help** who might be experienced with this technology in a big way for reference.

=> Is it **better** than Web Forms ? Does MVC Application fully give an alternate solution to the traditional Web Forms .

Please share your thoughts on this matter.

Thanks,

Mangesh

Comment: Not so sure this is the kind of question to post here. Have you tried MSDN? Or any Microsoft forum, etc?

Comment: I think the scope if this question is too wide. Please try splitting it into small, concrete SO questions that all have a *single answer*.

Comment: I agree with the commenters ,but I wonder where should such questions go ?

Comment: _"viability of designing a full scale ASP.NET MVC Application"_ - are you sure you don't mean web scale? Anyway your questions are too wide and open-ended. Yes, you can write a "heavy" application in MVC, but if you don't define "heavy" you can't say how heavy.

Comment: Examples: You are using one. StackOverflow is built on ASP.NET MVC 4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes Mvc application is fully capable to handle large data's and the architecture of application gives alot of
support to improve the performance of your application. But still it depends upon your coding methodology and code cleanness. How you can divide your project into layers or modules. You can use MVC unit testing feature side by side when any of your module is ready this makes comfartible in the end when you integrate all of your modules.

> > => Examples of Web applications designed in MVC which deal with a lot of traffic
> >     http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx
> >     http://www.sitefinity.com
> >
> > => Links on resources which can include sample projects , tutorials , lectures, Example Codes etc . 
> >     **Music store is the best application in Asp.net Mvc:
> >     http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store**
> >     
> >     => Expert Help who might be experienced with this technology in a big way for reference.
> >     
> >     **Sorry I cannot understand this question. But I think your questions is about pre-requisite to work in MVC. If you ever worked in Asp.net Web Forms and then switch in MVC then you understand the power of MVC technology.** 
> >     
> >     
> >     
> >     => Is it better than Web Forms ? Does MVC Application fully give an alternate solution to the traditional Web Forms . 
> >     
> >     
> >     **MVC is much much better option then Web Forms from my point of view. Because MVC gives a lot of support in term RAD and also a number of Jquery libraries is available where you can easily integrate Rich controls in your web application like
> >     Knockout.js: http://knockoutjs.com/
> >
> >     Angular.js: http://angularjs.org/
> >
> >     KendoUI.js: http://www.kendoui.com**
> >
> >     
> >     
> >     You can also see a lot of debates MVC vs WebForms:
> >     http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC